# FFmpeg libraries on Windows - Undefined References

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw

I am trying to use FFmpeg libraries available from [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) under Windows 10 (64 bits). I downloaded version=20181126-90ac0e5, architecture=Windows-64, Linking=Dev. There are 3 folders inside that FFmpeg folder: examples, lib and include.
To use these libraries I copied the contents of the "include" folder to the "include" folder of my MinGW installation. I also copied the contents of the "lib" folder to the "lib" folder of MinGW.
I try to compile the decode_video.c example that comes inside the examples folder with the following way:

```
 gcc decode_video.c -o decode_video.exe -lavcodec -lavutil -lavformat -lm
```

The compiler gives me these undefined references:

```
 undefined reference to `avcodec_send_packet'
 undefined reference to `avcodec_receive_frame'
 undefined reference to `av_packet_alloc'
 undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'
 undefined reference to `av_parser_init'
 undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
 undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'
 undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc'
 undefined reference to `av_parser_parse2'
 undefined reference to `av_parser_close'
 undefined reference to `avcodec_free_context'
 undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
 undefined reference to `av_packet_free'
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong here. Any guidance is very welcome.

Comment: Did you extern  “C” {} the includes?

Comment: The code is in C. Also I am compiling using gcc, not g++. Because of this it's necessary to use extern "C"{}. But I just did, just to be sure.

Comment: Correction: *it's not necessary